# How to fit dynamic content container between three fixed containers

Tags: html, css, positioning

Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/LuSBF/2/

```
<div class="headmenu">
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="leftmenu">
    left
</div>
<div class="rightmenu">
    right
</div>
<div class="maincontent">
    Lorem Ipsum i...

    <div class="footer">
        footer
</div>
</div>
```

Top, left and right are fixed and `.maincontent` must fit in them no matter the size of the window. Currently `.maincontent` overflows the available space and causes horizontal scrollbars.

```
.headmenu { background: #141414; height: 60px; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; }
.leftmenu { background: #c11718; height: 100%; width: 100px; position: fixed; margin-top: 60px; top: 0; }
.rightmenu { background: #141414; height: 100%; width: 200px; position: fixed; margin-top: 60px; right: 0; top: 0; }
.footer { background: #141414; height: 60px; width: 100%; bottom: 0; }

#logo { background: url('imgs/logo.jpg'); width: 181px; height: 50px; margin: 5px 0 0 0; }

.maincontent { width: 79%; border: 1px solid blue; margin: 60px 200px 0 100px; }
```

How can I get `.maincontent` to fill only the available space between the header, right menu and left menu?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: how to make `maincontent` fit in `headmenu`, `leftmenu` and `rightmenu`?

Comment: You question is not clear at all, what are you asking? Why would you want to put maincontent inside 3 other elements, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `.maincontent` to this:

```
.maincontent { margin: 60px 200px 0 100px; }
```

There is no need to specify the width of this block-level element (since you want it fill the screen minus the margins). And without the proper `box-sizing` the border adds scrollbars.

You might also want to reset your CSS;

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Oh that's it.. damn, thanks. :) And thanks to those bastards voting down without any reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `position:absolute;` I'm on a mobile so can only give a general example of your code

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/LuSBF/3/